# Derivation of Ratio Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[Image of the derivation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ7C8.png)
I was studying the derivation of the ratio distribution of rvs given their joint density, but I don't understand what was made here when computing $D'(u)$. What rule was applied? Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! Please in the future [refrain from using images in your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem?noredirect=1&lq=1) and typeset the equations with MathJaX instead. Here is a [guide on how to use MathJaX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1) for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to compute the derivative of
$$D(u):=\mathbb P(U\le u) = \int_0^\infty\int_0^{ux}f(x,y)\ dydx + \int_{-\infty}^0\int_{ux}^{0}f(x,y)\ dydx $$
All you need is to apply (two times) the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) which tells you that
$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{du}\left[\int_0^\infty\int_0^{ux}f(x,y)\ dydx \right]&=\int_0^\infty\frac{d}{du}\left[\int_0^{ux}f(x,y)\ dydx\right] \\
&=\int_0^\infty\left[ f(x,ux)  \cdot\frac{d(ux)}{du}- f(x,0)  \cdot\frac{d(0)}{du} + \int_0^{ux}\frac{d}{du}f(x,y)dy\right]\end{align} $$
Apply it similarly on the integral from $-\infty $ to $0$ to get your result.